# Layout segmentation with Tesseract

Tags: java, tesseract

My goal is to import pdf documents (mostly scanned) and analyse the layout in IntelliJ / Java. Now I have a problem with tesseract to get the textboxes.

I don't want to get the Text recognized (no OCR) but the coordinates of the Textboxes in the document.

Two questions:

1. How can I import Tesseract to my current Java project without opening a test-class?
   If I try to use it in my normal class I always get an error:

   > Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no liblept in
   >   java.library.path
2. Has anyone the right Tesseract command to get the coordinates of the Text - and Image- boxes?

Comment: So to recap. you wish to know the spatial location of the text paragraphs/sections like left:20px top:100px width:500px height:207px?

Comment: Exactly, @Tschallacka. I already got the pixels of the complete Document but can't get to the locations of the text / image sections.

Comment: Ok. Please add that info a bit clearer into your question what your goals are. You can use the edit link for that.